# Typing a "camel caser" in Flow: variance issues?

Tags: covariance, flowtype

[try flow link](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBSAygPIByYAvGAHYCuMMYAPmAM4YBOAlrQOas69ALYAjPFyFi4cGHgCGtIQG8wAbU68BAXQBcRMpQC+QkhXU70UerQDGGHnGV2FIvDB4AvPAB5CBubkAHwAFABW7M6BAJSBYCqoYGBceBj0XMqRzqjG6HbOnMIiBgziktRgAIwATADMqAW0RWUAwm4e3ngAJqWiElI0ru6ePqFlMfmFGBzcBlp8gjQARAAWPGAYq5J4y43Ts1ztI129h4uVw51jWpP7zTNl7H3lXJaV6lUANDVfdVZNFqidjHa49F4Dd5DDqjPDjYF3QEzbo8BxOWgKLhYAxqTTcRb6YoDMCmGhqADWeGx1XqJPuRRRaOcmKwoNh3UuMK6oUZjmZWJiQA)

I've been messing around with typing a "camel caser" function (one that consumes JSON and camel cases its keys). I've run into a few issues along the way, and I'm curious if y'all have any suggestions.

A camel caser never changes the shape of its argument, so I would like to preserve the type of whatever I pass in; ideally, calling `camelize` on an array of numbers would return another array of numbers, etc.

I've started with the following:

```
type JSON = null | string | number | boolean | { [string]: JSON } | JSON[]
function camelize<J: JSON>(json: J): J {
    throw "just typecheck please"
}
```

This works great for the simple cases, `null`, `string`, `number`, and `boolean`, but things don't quite work perfectly for JSON dictionaries or array. For example:

```
const dictionary: { [string]: number } = { key: 123 }
const camelizedDictionary = camelize(dictionary)
```

will fail with a type error. A similar issue will come up if you pass in a value of, say, type `number[]`. I think I understand the issue: arrays and dictionaries are mutable, and hence invariant in the type of the values they point to; an array of numbers is *not* a subtype of `JSON[]`, so Flow complains. If arrays and dictionaries were covariant though, I believe this approach would work.

Given that they're not covariant though, do y'all have any suggestions for how I should think about this?

Comment: In the future it would be helpful if you included the actual type errors in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use property variance to solve your problem with dictionaries:

```
type JSON = null | string | number | boolean | { +[string]: JSON } | JSON[]
```

https://flowtype.org/blog/2016/10/04/Property-Variance.html

As for your problem with `Arrays`, as you've pointed out the issue is with mutability. Unfortunately `Array<number>` is not a subtype of `Array<JSON>`. I think the only way to get what you want is to explicitly enumerate all of the allowed `Array` types:

```
type JSON = null | string | number | boolean | { +[string]: JSON } | Array<JSON> | Array<number>;
```

I've added just `Array<number>` here to make my point. Obviously this is burdensome, especially if you also want to include arbitrary mixes of JSON elements (like `Array<string | number | null>`). But it will hopefully address the common issues.

(I've also changed it to the array syntax with which I am more familiar but there should be no difference in functionality).

There has been talk of adding a read-only version of `Array` which would be analogous to covariant object types, and I believe it would solve your problem here. But so far nothing has really come of it.

Complete [tryflow](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBSAygPIByYAvGAHYCuMMYAPmAM4YBOAlrQOas69ALYAjPFyFi4cGHgCGtIQG8wAagDanXgIC6ALiJlKAXyEBBLlwVYAPCQoA+S9dt2G4yU4Dc6KPS0AMYYPHDKQQoieDA8AF54DkaO5E4AFABW7OHJAJTJYCqoYGBceBj0XMpZ4aim6EHhnMIiRp4SUjQAjABMAMyojbTNngDCUTHxeAAmbaId1GCR0bEJaZ65DU0YHNxGOnyCNABEABY8YBinknjHg9u7XOMrU7OPh4vLk2s6m-fDO087DmXi4mj0i00XQAND1oX09P8RqJ2M9vjMQR1wZ8Jqs8OsUX8hs1pjwQmFaAouFgjGptNxDoYWgtzDQ1ABrPA0sC9PpgerEnak8nhKlYNF46Y4l5rYWhUXU3JAA) based on the one you gave.

Comment: Ok, cool, that's actually exactly what I ended up thinking of, adding extra cases like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Flow now supports [`$ReadOnly`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#readonlyt-) and [`$ReadOnlyArray`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/#toc-readonlyarray) so a different approach would be to define the `JSON` type as

```
type JSON = 
  | null 
  | string 
  | number 
  | boolean 
  | $ReadOnly<{ [string]: JSON }> 
  | $ReadOnlyArray<JSON>
```

This solves one of the issues noted above because `$ReadOnlyArray<number>` is a subtype of `$ReadOnlyArray<JSON>`.

This might not work depending on the implementation of the `camelize` function since it might modify the keys to be camel-case. But, it's good to know about the read-only utilities in Flow since they are powerful and allow for more concise and, possibly, more correct function types.