# Is it possible to refine a boundedly polymorphic type?

Tags: flowtype

[Try flow link.](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQjIFcB2BjALgS1uqABYC2JAPACoBcoA5AIZ2gA+9ARnQHwAUAHrUoBKQaADeiUKFyRQ-UAF4l9JkPGSpoAE4BTbKi2FGdDQF9QO6AGcd6zdr0GjnM4lNA)

Here's a simple bounded polymorphism example that doesn't work the way I'd expect it to:

```
// @flow

function thisBreaks<T: 'a' | 'b'>(x: T): T {
  if (x === 'a') {
    return 'a'
  } else {
    return 'b'
  }
}

function thisWorks<T: 'a' | 'b'>(x: T): T {
  return x
}

const a = 'a'
const aPrime: 'a' = thisWorks(a)
const b = 'b'
const bPrime: 'b' = thisWorks(b)

5:     return 'a'              
               ^ string. This type is incompatible with the expected return type of
3: function thisBreaks<T: 'a' | 'b'>(x: T): T {   
   ^ some incompatible instantiation of `T`

7:     return 'b'              
               ^ string. This type is incompatible with the expected return type of
3: function thisBreaks<T: 'a' | 'b'>(x: T): T {   
   ^ some incompatible instantiation of `T`
```

I would have expected the first example to work, since e.g. the `x === 'a'` check could refine `T` to `'a'`, right?

Comment: While it's not possible, you might be able to accomplish what you want to do with function intersections.  I created a working type for your function: [Try flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzCjjgC4wAKCgD3IHIBDOgSjAF4A+MRl1MfgQIBklGvQBGLdlzqTmqNqOrSwytuu5MwAfk10wEluQbYAnvMw4CYcQwBO9LYuJwKPeVjyFbAL0PsiEjc5Sy8iBgBLGFxHfWcg2V4gA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible and shouldn't be possible. Here is an example that shows why:

```
function test<T: number | string>(x: T): T {
  if (typeof x === 'number') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 'b'
  }
}

test((5: 5));
```

The function is supposed to return value of type `5`, but returns `1` instead.

So, what happens? We have some unknown type `T` and we know that `T` <: `string | number` (`T` is subtype of `string | number`). After we refine `x`, we know that `T` is a subtype of `number`. It doesn't mean that `T` **is** `number`. It can be `5`, like in the example, or `1 | 2 | 3`. Knowing that `T` is subtype of `number` is not enough to create a value of `T`. To do that we need to know lower bound of `T`, but there is no way to know it.

The last question is: why is you example apparently safe then? It's simple: if `T` <: `'a'`, then it can only be `'a'` (or `empty`, but it doesn't really matter). There are no other subtypes of `'a'`. So, theoretically, Flow could support that, but its not very practical: if you know that `x` is `'a'`, than you can just return `x`

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I saw your response to https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3219. I was definitely not thinking about the implications of such specific types.

Comment: The actual issue that motivated my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496896/typing-a-camel-caser-in-flow-variance-issues. Am I right that there just isn't a great way to give camelize an accurate flow type?

Comment: Right. The only way to produce something of type T is to take something that already has type T.